# Does an IF NOT EXISTS mySQL query exist?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

just doing an INSERT using mySQL which works fine...

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO FLIGHTS_AVAILABLE 
 (aircraftID, aircraftType, maxSeats) VALUES('$theaircraftID', '$addType', '$maxCapacity'      ) ") 
or die(mysql_error());  

 echo '<p>';
 echo "The following details were added into the database:";
 echo "<hr>";

  echo $theaircraftID . $addType . $maxCapacity;
```

This works fine, however I've looked online and whilst I have heard of a feature called IF NOT EXISTS, there are not very good explanations online about it's use.

Is there anyway, I can run this query above, providing that if for example $theaircraftID = 10, and there is already a row in the database where the aircraftID = 10, then the query would not be run?

Thanks for any help you may be able to suggest,

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `'FLIGHTS_AVAILABLE'.'aircraftID'`. MySQL will block additional `INSERT`s with the same value. Additionally you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY EXISTS` to run an `UPDATE` incase the `INSERT` give a `DUPLICATE KEY` constraint error.

Comment: Sure, I'll give that a go, thanks. Is there anyway then, I can echo my own error message as well if the INSERT message isn't executed due to the unique index? Thanks @FritsvanCampen – Tom Gillespie 6 secs ago edit

Comment: Yea, you can use `mysql_errno` and `mysql_error` to get details about the error. Duplicate key constraint errors have a unique `errno`. That should give you robust enough exception handling.

Comment: @FritzvanCampen Perhaps I didn't explain myself well, I meant more along the lines of if the INSERT doesn't work due to the mysql_error brought about by the unique index, could I then say echo "Values added"; etc..

Comment: Oh I see, you're doing a mass insert. Yea, that's tricky. I'm not sure how to get proper feedback on those, I don't think you can actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create unique index by required columns and then use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) and [mysql_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).